# Constants as a byte?

Tags: java, constants

All the code I have written or read, I have seen integral constants declared something like,

```
public static final int CONSTANT = 1;
```

But, I have been seeing recently some instances of constants declared as,

```
public static final byte CONSTANT = 1;
```

in a new codebase of ours. Both accomplish the constant semantics but `byte` seems to be highly *unpopular*

Is there any argument in favor of having `int`'s as constants or am I just overthinking stuff?

Comment: Beside that int is 32 bits while byte is 8?

Comment: Maybe you are just overthinking and this constant is used by function that takes byte and not int, so you avoid adding a downcast

Answer (score 2):

It should only depend on where the constant needs to be used and what the expected type is at that location.

Suppose you are implementing some type of file or binary data format, and you need constants that fit into a byte, it makes sense to use a `byte`

```
public static final byte RECORD_START = 1;
public static final byte FIELD_TYPE_NUMBER = 2;

// ...

ByteBuffer b;
b.put(RECORD_START);
b.put(FIELD_TYPE_NUMBER);
```

But if the data type where you use the constant is `int`, then you should use `int` for the type of constant too.

An `int` is 32 bits and a `byte` is 8 bits.
But if you have so many constants that the memory usage of the constant values is a concern, then it was probably a wrong choice to use constants (you should probably be storing the data in a file in that case)

Answer (score 0):

Well i guess the advantages would be the same of it is a constant or not, `byte` takes up less memory therefore it would be better suited in those suited in those situation where a constant in the range of `-128 - 127`. The only real difference i can think of is, that since it is a constant, you have a guarantee, that the value is not going to change.

Answer (score 0):

I think declaring a constant as a byte can improve readability in some cases where the values of the constants are used as bytes in the end.

One example for this is APDUs that are sent to a smartcard. These are just a sequence of bytes. You might want to create a constant for the instruction byte (which is always the second byte in the APDU). If you would create the constant as an int, this could cause confusion when reading the code. Why would someone create the constant for a byte as an int? How will it be converted to the byte in the end? At what point in the code is it converted? What happens with the possibly contained additional information of the int? Such questions do not come up if you declare the constant as a byte right away.

I do not know your code, so I cannot say if this applies to your case. But anyhow, this is one reason to create a constant as a byte instead of integer.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a constant of type `byte`, you can pass it as a parameter declared as `byte`, whereas an `int` constant would require and explicit cast.

Also, if you're using a class that has overloaded methods, and there is both a method with an `int` argument and another with a `byte` argument, you would not invoke the same method if you pass a constant of type `int` or a constant of type `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

Well the main advantage of using int (or long for that point) is a question of code readability. Constants are often used as input for functions, so by using byte casts would be necessary. Further for maintainability it is a good practice to have the same dataType for the same functionality of Objects. for example ids should always be long etc, however this is a question of your teams conventions. Therefore if constants for numbers are usually integers, than it is good practice to always use integers to reduce code obscurification.